# calculate the df.describe() for each value in a column and recreate a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Imagine the following data frame:

```
d={‘cluster’: [1,1,3,4,2,2],
   ‘Weight‘: [65, 70, 68, 75, 78, 62],
   ‘Height’: [170, 173, 174, 180, 184, 167]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Now, how to use a for loop to return a dataframe that calculate the average weight and height for each value in cluster.

If I write stupid codes will be like this:

```
#creating subsets and concat
a=pd.DaFrame(df[df[‘cluster’]==1].describe().loc[‘mean’])
b= pd.DaFrame(df[df[‘cluster’]==2].describe().loc[‘mean)
....
DF= pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
```

It will be ridiculous when there are more clusters in a column.

Thank you.

Comment: df.groupby('cluster').mean()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

d={'cluster': [1,1,3,4,2,2],
   'Weight': [65, 70, 68, 75, 78, 62],
   'Height': [170, 173, 174, 180, 184, 167]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df.groupby('cluster').agg(['mean'])
```

This implementation also has the benefit that you can add further aggregation-based functions (e.g. median) in the future if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

d={'cluster': [1,1,3,4,2,2],
   'Weight': [65, 70, 68, 75, 78, 62],
   'Height': [170, 173, 174, 180, 184, 167]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

newdf = df.groupby('cluster').describe().iloc[:,1]
print(newdf)
```

EDIT: WeNYoBen does it better if you want only the means/don't need to pick anything else from `describe()`